# Make a perfectly transparent textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can make the background and borders (partially) of a textarea transparent by doing -

```
<textarea id="one" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)">
</textarea>
```

However, **there is still a couple of slanting lines in the bottom right corner of the textarea** which I cannot remove! Also, **border of textarea reappears when textarea is in focus**. 
 
How can I make a perfectly transparent textarea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the resize to none

```
<textarea id="one" style="resize: none;background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Also, `outline: none` is needed to remove the border when it's focused

Answer (score 1):

```
#one {
background: none;  // no bg means already transparent if no color wanted
border: none; // no border  , but if exist add !important to style
}
```

hi just make border to none and background to none rather then making rgba(0, 0, 0, 0).